# No wireless networks listed since upgrade from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, 15.04

PVC is a Dell 1545.  dual booting Windows 7 & Ubuntu.  I upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 yesterday morning, all worked ok including wireless connection.

Then a few hours later upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04.  Since that point I have no wireless connections listed at all.

Wireless works fine in Windows by the way.

In Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab, I have Broadcom Corp BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card) listed, under which the 'Using Broadcom .....' option is listed and selected.

I have tried multiple 'solutions' from various support pages all day without any success.  Several mention running nm-tool at the command prompt - this tool is not present on my system ! (command not found).

Assistance (in plain English if possible) would be much appreciated !  A lot of what I have read might as well have been in a foreign language.

Nick

Answer (score 2):

Please obtain a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or any other means. Next, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: My issue resolved by this solution.

Answer (score 1):

It won't let me comment, and I'm not sure if this is the correct answer, but I have no choice other than posting it.

I had the same problem, and, if I remember correctly, I managed to correct it by downloading the bcmwl-kernel-source package manually.

Download the package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/bcmwl-kernel-source). I used a flash disk and manually installed it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i [bcmwl-kernel-source debian].deb
```

After installing that package, I was able to connect to my network and ran the following commands to install the additional drivers that Ubuntu offers (you can also do this through the Additional Drivers GUI, but this tool won't work until you are connected to a network):

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: It is not the correct answer.

Comment: It is indeed. I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 for a friend and had no wifi. This brought the wifi on. Didn't do the dpkg part though, just the ubuntu-drivers. Was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Additional package was needed for my Dell-Vostro 1015 bcmwl-kernel-source and it was available from apt-get.
Thanks